# Нужно составить программу в Python,которая вычисляет размер максимальной последовательности положительных чисел в одномерном массиве

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста.Не понимаю почему не обрабатывает дальше первой последовательности

```
n=10
a=[-1, 0, 1, 2, -2, 1, -2, 1, 2, 3, 3]
print (a)
lmax=0
l=0
i=0
while i<n:
    if a[i]>0:
         l+=1
    else:
        if l>lmax:
            lmax=l
        l=0
    i+=1
print (lmax)
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас все правильно, кроме одного момента, вы получаете ответ в переменной `l` или `lmax`. Поскольку условие для `else` может никогда не выполнится, то ответ будет только в `l`. Можете проверить, выведя в конце `print (lmax,l)` или сразу большее `print (lmax if lmax > l else l)`. Думаю дальше вы уже сами сможете решить, как улучшить существующий код.

И лучше сразу вычисляйте длину массива программно, потом его легче будет править, сейчас у вас массив больше чем 10 элементов:

```
.....
while i<len(a):
    .....
```

Comment: Спасибо)Попробую доработать

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще через генератор списков:

```
import itertools as it

a=[-1, 0, 1, 2, -2, 1, -2, 1, 2, 3, 3]

res=max([list(x) for (k, x) in it.groupby(a, lambda x: x>0) if k], key=len)
print(res)
```

Получим сам список:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```

Либо

```
print(len(res))
```

Получим его длину:

```
4
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное,попробую доработать код,что бы когда нет положительных чисел,программа выводила  'ошибка'

Comment: @user321095 - это просто реализуется. если в списке вообще нет положительный чисел, то в моем коде `res` будет равен пустому списку `([])`, а булево значение пустого списка - `False`. То есть, ваше условие будет `if not res: <ругаемся на ошибку отсутствия положительных чисел>`